# Resolve Dependency in unit test cases angular 4 in a layered structure

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to angular and working on Unit test case for my project. I went through some articless [Unit Testing](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/overview/)

After reading these articles when I try to write unit test case for my project i am not able to resolve dependency in my test cases. As I have a layered structure and when I inject dependency in my test cases  which in turn are calling other layer there dependency are not resolved. I am not able to find out how to resolve the dependency to execute the test case.

I have a LoginComponent class
a AuthService class
and a HttpService class

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpService } from '../../common/services/http.service';
import {LocalStorageService} from '../../common/services/local-storage.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../common/services/auth.service';
import {PathConfig} from '../../common/config/path.config';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-login',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginForm: FormGroup;
  public submitted: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router, 
              private httpService: HttpService,
              private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
              private authService: AuthService,
              private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  ngOnInit () {
    this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('testmarion', [Validators.required]),
      pwd: new FormControl('testmarion', [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  doLogin(value: any, isValid: boolean ) {
    if (isValid) {
      this.authService.login(PathConfig.LOGIN, value)
      .then((data:any)=> {
           this.localStorageService.set("userInfo",JSON.stringify(data.response));
           this.localStorageService.set("AuthToken",data.response.AccessToken);
           this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }).
      catch(err => {
        this.toastr.error(err.message);
  });

    }
  }
}
```

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {LocalStorageService} from "./local-storage.service";
import {ConstantConfig} from "../config/constant.config";
import {HttpHeaders} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor ( private http:HttpClient , private localStorage:LocalStorageService) {}
    //Auth REQUEST
    login(url,obj: Object): Promise<any>{
      let body = JSON.stringify(obj); 
       let modifyUrl = url +'?userName='+obj['name']+'&'+'password='+obj['pwd'];
        return this.http.get(modifyUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then((res:any) => {
          console.log(res);
         return ({'response':res})
        }).catch((error:any) => { return Promise.reject( error || 'Server error')}  )
    }

    //check login status
   isLoggedIn():boolean{
       var data = this.localStorage.get(ConstantConfig.AUTH_TOKEN);
       return data ? true : false ;
   }
}
```

```
import {Injectable, Inject}     from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import {LocalStorageService} from "./local-storage.service";
import {ConstantConfig} from "../config/constant.config";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  // Resolve HTTP using the constructor
  constructor (private http: HttpClient ,@Inject(LocalStorageService)private localStorage:LocalStorageService) {}

  // GET REQUEST
  get(url) : Observable<any>{

    // Create a request option
    let options = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
         'Authorization': this.localStorage.get(ConstantConfig.AUTH_TOKEN)
      },

    };

    //using get request
   // return this.http.get(url,options)
   return this.http.get(url)
    // and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .map((res:any) => res ).catch((err:any) => Observable.throw(err['error'] || err || 'Server error'))

  }

  //POST REQUEST
  post(url,obj: Object): Observable<any> {
      let body    = obj
      let options = { headers: {
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
          'Authorization': this.localStorage.get(ConstantConfig.AUTH_TOKEN)
      } }; // Create a request option

    //using post request
    return this.http.post(url, body, options) //using post request
      .map((res:any) => res ) //and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .catch((err:any) =>  Observable.throw(err['error'] || err || 'Server error')); //errors if any
  }


}
```

the doLogin function in component class calls the login function in the AuthService class which calls the get method of httpservice to make a api hit.

I am trying to create unit test case for doLogin function.
For this in login.component.spec.ts file what I tried is created an instance of login component by injecting dependencies in the constructor now when I call the doLogin function with my object in my unit test I get the error that cannot call Login function of undefined. Same case is when I use TestBed.

I am not able to figure out how do I resolve the dependencies of the services.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock your components.

For instance, that's how you mock a service :

```
const authMock = {
  login: () => Promise.resolve(true),
  isLoggedIn: () => true
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: AuthService, useValue: authMock }
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

In your `authMock` variable, you will need to put every function, every variable that you have in your service. This way, when your tested component calls the service, it actually calls your mock.

You can then mock the returns like so :

```
it('should call the service if the form is valid', () => {
  spyOn(component['authService'], login).and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({data: 'anything you want there'}));

  component.doLogin('value', true);

  expect(component['authService'].login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(PathConfig.LOGIN, 'value');
});
```